# Android, how does looping work ? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make an application (in Kotlin) just for practice but it looks like I'm not using `isLooping` correctly because when I launch the app, I can play only my audio but non stop it when clicking again. So I think the loop is the problem.

I'm doing :

```
sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cena)
sound.isLooping = true
```

Here is my full code :

```
package com.example.firstapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var sound: MediaPlayer
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val play = findViewById<Button>(R.id.play)
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cena)
        sound.isLooping = true
        playBtnClick()
    }
    private fun playBtnClick() {

        if (!sound.isPlaying) {
            play.setOnClickListener {
                sound.start()
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop)
            }
        }
        else {
                sound.pause()
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the isPlaying inside the onClickListener, because your onCreate() method gets called only once while activity gets created and it starts playing. There is no any event after that.

Modified your code. Use below code instead,

```
package com.example.firstapp
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var sound: MediaPlayer
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val play = findViewById<Button>(R.id.play)
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cena)
        sound.isLooping = true

        play.setOnClickListener {

            if(sound.isPlaying()){
                sound.pause();
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop)
            } else {
                sound.start();
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that playBtnClick is called only once, probably you should put a call to the playBtnClick method play.setOnCLickListener ()

```
  lateinit var sound: MediaPlayer
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val play = findViewById<Button>(R.id.play)
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cena)
        sound.isLooping = true
        play.setOnClickListener {
           playBtnClick();
        }
    }
    private fun playBtnClick() {

        if (!sound.isPlaying) {
                sound.start()
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop)
        }
        else {
                sound.pause()
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play)
            }
        }
```